# Parse each line of a strictly formatted text file into an array of 3-element rows

Tags: php, string, text-parsing

I have a text file in which each line is an entry.
each line has certain words separated by space and 2 -3 words at the end of the entry with brackets

eg.

```
asd asdasd asdasd {m} [jsbbsdfb]
```

how do I get the following result in php

```
$data[0]="asd asdasd asdasd"

$data[1]= "{m}"

$data[2]= "[jsbbsdfb]"
```

Comment: What have you tried? theres a couple of ways of splitting strings, with split, reg expressions etc. Show us what you tried, we can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `strpos` to find the right parts or you can use `preg_match` (regular expressions), both have their own (dis)advantages. Using `preg_match` you can do this is as little as one line, but it is relatively slow and not as easy to use. I would do something like this:

```
while(/* $line is next line available */) {
  $brace_position = strpos($line, '{');
  $bracket_position = strpos($line, '[');

  $data = array(
    substr($line, 0, ($brace_position - 1),
    substr($line, $brace_position, ($backet_position - $brace_position - 1)),
    substr($line, $bracket_position)
  );
}
```

The other answer provided above, by wired00,  are correct too, but **only** if each line is exactly the same in length (i.e. the same amount of words an spaces). The answer by check123 is not a correct answer to your question.

*See **strauberry's answer** for the regular expression which I mentioned in above.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$regex = '/([a-zA-Z ]*) (\{[a-zA-Z]\}) (\[[a-zA-Z]+\])/';
$yourText = "asd asdasd asdasd {m} [jsbbsdfb]";
$lines = explode("\n", $yourText);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $result = array();
    preg_match($line, $regex, $result);
    print_r($result);
}
```

You can tune the regex of course :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>$a = explode(" ",$string);
     $a[1] //will store first word of your string
     $a[2] // and so on until the end of the string</s>

Ok! I got it wrong above. You might want to try something like:

```
$str = "asd asdasd asdasd {m} [jsbbsdfb]";
$k=strlen($str);
for($i=0;$i<$k;$i++) {
    $char = substr($str,$i,1);
    //do your operation here on
}
```

and loop through each character of the string and operate as required.

Comment: That would split his string into 5 parts.. He'd do better to do it by { and then by [ for the second half.

Comment: This is not the proper answer to this @check123

Comment: But it seems his brackets and words do not have space in between them, so explode may be helpful.

Comment: see his example output and think about the output that your answer will produce. DO they match? I guess not.

Comment: @coding-Freak: ok! got the difference!

Comment: You both guys are right, I just over-looked his requirements. My Mistake.

Answer (score 0):

few ways... you could try exploding on the spaces... then concatenate the first 3 array elemnents together

something like this:

```
$yourString = "asd asdasd asdasd {m} [jsbbsdfb]";
$elements = explode ( " " , $yourString);

$string1 = $elements[0] . $elements[1] . $elements[2];
$string2 = $elements[3];
$string3 = $elements[4];
```

you could obviously then just set the values into first 3 elements of the array if you wanted

ie:

```
$yourString = "asd asdasd asdasd {m} [jsbbsdfb]";
$elements = explode ( " " , $yourString);

$elements[0] = $elements[0] . $elements[1] . $elements[2];
$elements[1] = $elements[3];
$elements[2] = $elements[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = "asd asdasd asdasd {m} [jsbbsdfb]";

$a1 = strpos($x, '{');
$a2 = strpos($x, '}', $a1);
$b1 = strpos($x, '[', $a2);
$b2 = strpos($x, ']', $b1);

$data = array();
$data[] = substr($x, 0, $a1-1);
$data[] = substr($x, $a1+1, $a2-$a1-1);
$data[] = substr($x, $b1+1, $b2-$b1-1);

var_dump($data);
```